# Insert / Toggle JSON elements/Objects with javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

Here's --> [My Code in JS Fiddle :)](https://jsfiddle.net/s0bkqsdx/7/)

My problem is when i click on the button "Prev". The name from the json file(for example) **Angela**
(from data - persons - knows- Angela) another name can also be used!

The name should be shown between "Angie" and "Menu", and then saved to local storage when i navigate to other pages, the best method for me would be toggle.

In my original code im using the p5.js library, so i do not think it would work with jquery.

```js
data = {
"persons": [{
    "name": "Angie",
    "link": "Angie.html",
    "knows": [ "Angela", 
                "Mona"
             ]
},    
{
    "name": "Rana",
    "link": "Rana.html",
    "knows": ["Mona"]
},
{
    "name": "Tamara",
    "link": "Tamara.html",
    "knows": [ "Angela", 
               "Claudia"
             ]
}
]}

for (var key in data) { 
   for (var i = 0; i < data[key].length; i++) {
      var name = data[key][i].name;
      var link = data[key][i].link;
      var menu_bar = document.createElement('a');
      menu_bar.className = 'menu_bar';
      menu_bar.innerHTML =

    '<a class="Main-Path" href="'+ link +'">' + name + '</a>';

    document.getElementById('persons').appendChild(menu_bar);

  }

}
```

```css
body 
{
margin: 0;
font-family: Arial;
}
.top-container 
{
background-color: #f1f1f1;
padding: 2px;
text-align: center;
}
div.scrollmenu {
background-color: #0000A0;
overflow: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu" id="persons">

<a href="index.html"> Menu </a>

</div>

<button id="Button" style="float:left;"> Prev </button>
```

I would be very thankful and you would save my day!

Comment: you can see it on the JSFiddle webpage under Menu

Comment: In the HTML yes it's there, but you haven't attempted to bind it to a click event within JS. What does this code need with a prev button anyhow?

Comment: When i click on "prev" the name "Angela" for example should be inserted before "Angie".
Angela is from Angie --> knows.
The Menu would be looking like:
[Menu Angela Angie Rana Tamara]

Comment: So some type of recursion, put some JS that tries to make the prev button function as best as you can then we can help you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s0bkqsdx/16/ @zer00ne
I tried this method like you see in the js fiddle link